# What will be the effects on the stocks of a mining company if they find a new deposit of metals and minerals

Tags: stock-analysis, financial-statements, historical-analysis

I recently heard of a large mining company called The Metals Company about to mine  the Clarion-Clipperton Zone,its larger than all the mineral deposits on land put together .Will this have a significant effect on its stocks in the coming year in a positive way , if so what sort of things should i be looking at when i run a financial background check on the company in the coming months to make investment decisions on it.

Comment: Depends on the rest of the market, demand for those minerals, how much they are able to extract at what cost...

Comment: I mean, mining nodules on the seabed has only been talked about for 50+ years. Successfully used as a cover story for the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glomar_Explorer and that is about it.

Answer (score 3):

The abstract idea of the stock market is that the current price of the stock already accounts for all currently available public information pertaining to the value and profits of the company.

At the point in time when The Metals Company made public that they are going to mine the Clarion-Clipperton Zone there stock probably jumped upwards but if you look at the stock price now this effect is already included.

If the mining works out better than currently expected the stock will go up. If it does worse than currently expected it will go down. Plenty of other events that can happen in the future will impact the stock price as well.